# Use Calendar API Java

Tags: java, api, calendar

I have an objective for TimeOfDay objects.I need help writing getTimeForDay method.Code will be provided later.I want to write this method such that given a Calendar Object,it returns a new Calendar Object with identical year,month and day, but with the time of day associated with this instance.
Code is:

```
import java.util.Calendar;

public class TimeOfDayImpl implements TimeOfDay,Cloneable,Comparable<TimeOfDay> {

    private byte minute;
    private byte hour;
    public TimeOfDayImpl(byte min,byte hr) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(TimeOfDay o) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public byte hour() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public byte minute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public Calendar getTimeForDay(Calendar referenceDay) {
        referenceDay.getInstance();
        referenceDay.
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    public TimeOfDay clone() throws CloneNotSupportedException 
    {
        return (TimeOfDay) super.clone();
    }
}
```

Comment: Let me get this in my head.  You want to return a new instance of `Calendar` whose `year`, `month`, and `day` are the same as the `referenceDay`, but whose time would be "now"?

Comment: And what part of the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) hasn't being able to help you??

Comment: I am a beginner to Calendar API.I am sure things will make sense in a while,but I have to get this done soon.I don't want you to tell me code,if you could just guide me how to go about it,I will atleast be on some track.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You should make the [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) your first point of call.  A little effort goes a long way ;).  If you have already tried looking through them, make sure you state what problems you had with finding the answer, because, yes, they can sometimes be very confusing :P

```
public Calendar getTimeForDay(Calendar referenceDay) {
    // Create a new Calendar, which should equal "NOW"
    Calendar timeOfDay = Calendar.getInstance();
    // Transfer the year, month and date values from our reference calendar
    // to our "NOW" calendar...
    // Include our hour and minute values, not that I'm zeroing out the seconds
    timeOfDay.set(
            referenceDay.get(Calendar.YEAR), 
            referenceDay.get(Calendar.MONTH), 
            referenceDay.get(Calendar.DATE),
            (int)hour(),
            (int)minute(),
            0);
    // Return the result
    return timeOfDay;
}
```

Comment: thanks but can you explain to me how you are taking care of minute and second issue?

Comment: I also have one confusion.Above in the code,I have a method public byte hour().Do you think this is getter and setter method?

Comment: 1- `Calendar` is taking care of the time it self.  A new instance of `Calendar` is the same as creating a new `Date` object, they are automatically synced to the current date and time.  So the returned value will be the current time (with some minor difference in the milliseconds ;)) but with the `year`, `month`, `date` of the `referenceDay`...

Comment: great! thanks and thanks for introducing me to Java docs.It helped :)

Comment: 2- I would say your `hour` method is a getter, because it does not take a parameter to change the value...Was I suppose to seed the new `Calendar` with these values?

Comment: as a matter of fact, yes.I am on the whole pretty new to Java.Hence such a basic question here :)

Comment: I've updated the example to include your `hour` and `minute` values :P

Comment: I obviously have problems with simple questions :P